# Como alterar aparência e comportamento dos botões "Abrir" e "Cancelar" do JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, arquivo

Bom pessoal, estou tentando usar o JFileChooser para selecionar diretórios e também arquivos. O que estou usando ate agora é

```
public void buscaFile() {
    File[] diretorio = null;
    diretorio = selectDir();
    if(diretorio != null) {
        for(File i : diretorio) {
            String[] add = { i.toString(), "aguarde"};
            System.out.println("DIR "  + i.toString());
          }
    }
    return;
}   
private static File[] selecionaDir() {
    File caminho = new File("C:\\");
    JFileChooser arq = new JFileChooser(caminho);
    arq.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    arq.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    int showOpenDialog = arq.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (showOpenDialog != arq.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return null;
    }
    File[] uploadDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    return uploadDir;
}
```

[image: o que é mostrado a partir desde código é.]

Porem a ideia é que ao invés de os botões Abri e Cancelar seja Adicionar e OK.
Para que cada vez que a pessoa clique em adicionar o caminho selecionado é salvo, e quando terminar de selecionar tudo que se precise basta clicar em OK.

Comment: Não sei se vai funcionar do jeito que você quer, mas já tentou usar [`setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29)? Isso permitirá a seleção de mais de um arquivo (só não sei se é possível selecioná-los em pastas diferentes). Customizar o texto dos botões é fácil, há o `setApproveButtonText` e *acho* que deve ter opção semelhante pro botão de cancelar. Se isso não for suficiente, sugiro no seu próprio código um loop que seleciona um caminho, abre o dialog de novo, etc, até o usuário escolher tudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pessoal eu consegui chegar onde queria, ou melhor já deu pra começar...

O código ficou como mostra a baixo, o que estou fazendo é capitando todo tipo de seleção e o que fiz com o botão *abrir* foi mudar o texto nele nada mais, porém quando pego o endereço dos diretórios selecionados eu chamo o método novamente.

O código:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Cizo
 */
public class MyFileChooser extends JFrame {

    public void seleciona() {

        File diretorio = new File("C:\\");

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(diretorio);
        fileChooser.resetChoosableFileFilters();
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText", "Seleçao de aquivos");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "Local");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonText", "Inserir");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Sair");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "Nome do Arquivo");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "Tipo de Arquivo");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText", "Abrir Selecionado");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText", "Sair");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameHeaderText", "Nome do Arquivo");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText", "Subir Nivel Acima");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText", "Desktop");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText", "Nova Pasta");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText", "Lista");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderButtonText", "Criar Nova Pasta");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.renameFileButtonText", "Renomear");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.deleteFileButtonText", "Apagar");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.filterLabelText", "Tipo de Arquivos");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText", "Detalhes");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileSizeHeaderText", "Tamanho");
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileDateHeaderText", "Data de Modificação");

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(fileChooser);

        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        File[] dir = null;
        switch (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this)) {

            case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:

                dir = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();

                for (File dir1 : dir) {
                    System.out.println("AQUI > " + dir1);
                }
                seleciona();
                break;

            case JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final");
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

O JFileChooser ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]